# grep with delimiters in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Hi I have a log file and I am doing grep operations like this.

```
cat logfile | grep select

2018-03-20T15:26:34,397 INFO  [2da4e66f-6092-46a7-9542-60afc0611205 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-32([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:compile(429)) - Compiling command(queryId=hive_20180320152634_a6ef02a1-e018-4085-8ceb-8a8d2733b427): select * from reportingperiod limit 5
2018-03-20T15:26:37,761 INFO  [HiveServer2-Background-Pool: Thread-35([])]: ql.Driver (Driver.java:execute(1735)) - Executing command(queryId=hive_20180320152634_a6ef02a1-e018-4085-8ceb-8a8d2733b427): select * from reportingperiod limit 5
```

I am trying to extract the query part based on the delimiter like this

```
delimiter based extract, first delimiter ': ' upto '\n'
```

So that I can get the expect output like this.

```
select * from reportingperiod limit 5
```

Initially the query extract I tried with regex and grep -OE methods. Right now I am trying to implement a generic method, So that any query will be captured.

I tried like this.

```
IFS=$': '
for i in `cat logfile`; do    echo $i; 
done
```

The above code is not working as expected, Since I don't know how to pass the second delimiter to extract the query. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want anything between the last `: ` and the end of line? I.e. do you assume that the desired queries never contain a `: `? Seems risky. On the other hand trying to recognise SQL-syntax with regex is tough. Can more be assumed about the syntax of your input lines? E.g. can we assume that there will always be something like `command(queryId=hive_20180320152634_a6ef02a1-e018-4085-8ceb-8a8d2733b427): ` before?

Comment: I belive you have to be a bit clearer here. Several issues I see are : (1) there are multiple ':' per line, so do you want to extract from the first or the last one? (2) The log file contains a compiling line and an executing line. Do you want both per `queryId`. Please provide us with a real input example and the real expected output.

Comment: Yes there is multiple ': ' but all the queries ended with /n. So I am thinking like last ': ' and the newline

Comment: @TejuPriya See the below answer which will provide what you request.

Comment: So you do assume that your queries never contain a `: `?

Comment: @Yunnosch it contains ': '

Comment: Don't you see a problem there? If your query contains a `: ` and you only look after the last `: ` then you get only part of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are interested in is :

```
awk -F ':' '/select/{print $NF}' <logfile>
```

be aware that you write from the first `:` till the end of line. However, in your example there are multiple `:` per line.

You could also just use `sed` to accomplish the same :

```
sed '/select/!{d};s/.*: *//' <logfile>
```

Comment: Hi I tried the awk and sed. The awk works for me as expected. but the sed doesn't works for me. really thanks for your solution. the awk method works like charm!

Comment: @TejuPriya I fixed the `sed`, there was a minor problem.

Comment: sure let me try the sed one

Comment: the sed regex has a missing dot

Comment: @mjz19910 please elaborate

Comment: i thought they wanted the delimiter to be ': ' not :(0-inf spaces)

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use cut as well.

My opinion is that you should use the most simple tool that satisfies your requirements, so this is probably a bit better.

print all, after first `:`

```
cut -d ':' -f 2- <file>
```

print stuff after first 2 fields.

```
echo xxx:yyy:zzz | cut -d ':' -f -2 --complement
```